# getStringExtra() return null

Tags: android

I try to send extra data of string by intent to a function, but I receive null.

here is the intent.put:

```
 private void takePicFromGallery(String nameOfButton) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    **intent.putExtra(NAME_OF_BUTTON, nameOfButton.toString());**
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "choose picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
```

and here is the the getting:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String nameOfButton = data.getStringExtra(NAME_OF_BUTTON);
    switch (nameOfButton) {
        case "ibMainPicture": {
            ibMainPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
        case "imageButton1": {
            imageButton1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: basically you should not expect that you will receive your extras in the result intent, as it is completely different intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent received during onActivityResult is not the same intent which you are creating in the takePicFromGallery method. The intent you are starting is consumed by the Activity opened and it sends a new intent back to your application.

Option1(Preferred Option):

```
private static final int IB_MAIN_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE = 524;
private static final int IMAGE_BUTTON_1_REQUEST_CODE = 785;

private void takePicFromGallery(String nameOfButton) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    if(nameOfButton.equals("ibMainPicture")) {
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "choose picture"), IB_MAIN_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
    else if(nameOfButton.equals("imageButton1") {
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "choose picture"), IMAGE_BUTTON_1_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Then when getting the Result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == IB_MAIN_PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            ibMainPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else if(requestCode == IMAGE_BUTTON_1_REQUEST_CODE) {
            imageButton1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
private static String lastButtonClicked = null;

private void takePicFromGallery(String nameOfButton) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    lastButtonClicked = nameOfButton.toString();
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "choose picture"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
}
```

Then when getting the Result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(lastButtonClicked == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK || requestCode != PICK_FROM_GALLERY) {
        return;
    }
    switch (lastButtonClicked) {
        case "ibMainPicture": {
            ibMainPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
        case "imageButton1": {
            imageButton1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;
        }
        ...
}
```

Comment: so how can I send the name of clicked-button to the method onActivityResult?

Comment: @yosef Added a second option for if this solution is preferred for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a specific request code for each different button clicks instead of a generic `PICK_FROM_GALLERY`, then in the `onActivityResult` you can check the request code sent with the intent

Comment: its too long and not pretty